# Bigcommerce optimize Issue

Tags: nginx, bigcommerce, nginx-location, nginx-config

Big-commerce optimize:

```
Accept-Encoding header Nginx
Leverage browser caching
Specify a cache validator
Optimize the order of styles and scripts
```

In which file we can change add code to remove all these things use Nginx file. We have Cyber duck Connection access inside https://prnt.sc/nmdfjc inside which file to add code to solve speed load issue.

Answer (score 1):

These items cannot be changed. BigCommerce is a SaaS platform, and web-server configuration is not something you can change. If you require this kind of optimization, place a reverse-proxy like Varnish or CloudFlare in front of your store.

- Accept-Encoding header Nginx
- Leverage browser caching
- Specify a cache validator

> Optimize the order of styles and scripts

you have some control over that in /templates/layout/base.html.
some expressions are fixed, and you will not be able to change.

- `{{{snippet 'htmlhead'}}}`
- `{{{snippet 'footer'}}}`

If you require more control of this, you need to rewrite the HTML using a reverse-proxy.